# Set combo box by name

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, combobox, automation

When using VBA for automatic handling of Internet Explorer, you can select an item in a combo box, by its value. If our combo box `HTML` looks like this:

```
<select name="my_combo_box" id="fruits">
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Banana</option>
    <option value="3">Strawberry</option>
</select>
```

Then you can select the option "Banana" using VBA, like this:

```
getElementById("fruits").value = 2
```

But is there any way to select it using its name (display member), i.e. **Banana**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Banana" is not a HTML property, but the text between tags. 
You could loop through all elements and with option tag and then choose the one with desired innerText. In the next step, you could cut id from innerHTML. Like:

```
Sub MyMacro()
Dim opt As IHTMLElement
Dim iComboBox As IHTMLElement
Dim sID As String

For Each opt In iComboBox.getElementsByTagName("option")
    If InStr(opt.innerHTML, "Banana") Then
        sID = CutId(opt.innerHTML)
    End If
Next opt

End Sub


Function CutId(s As String) As String
Dim s As String

s = Mid(s, InStr(s, "=") + 2, 1)
CutId = s

End Function
```

Then you can use sId for selecting item. I guess that your HTML is just example, so it is possible that your will need to adjust CutId function, this is just my proposal for solution. Especially, you will adjust my code if you expect id to have two digits.

Comment: That is actually a pretty simple work around. And you are correct, the above is an example, the actual problem is very similar though, just a lot more difficult to read :-)